# create year-month-day sequence based on hour-minute column

Tags: r, time, lubridate

I have the following dataset:

```r
structure(list(Zeit = c("8:30:00 PM", "8:45:00 PM", "9:00:00 PM", 
"9:15:00 PM", "9:30:00 PM", "9:45:00 PM", "10:00:00 PM", "10:15:00 PM", 
"10:45:00 PM", "11:15:00 PM", "11:45:00 PM", "12:15:00 AM", "12:45:00 AM", 
"1:15:00 AM", "1:45:00 AM", "2:15:00 AM", "2:45:00 AM", "3:15:00 AM", 
"3:45:00 AM", "4:15:00 AM"), SRB = c(1.0397346014, 0.98344320764, 
0.78642332948, 0.7582776326, 0.67384054196, 0.51434825964, 0.46743876484, 
0.39238357316, 0.0827809074800001, 0.0264895137199999, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = 43:62, class = "data.frame")
```

As you can see, only the hour and minutes are provided in the timestamp. I would like to create a new column that contains the day, month and year, starting from 24/10/2023. The (original) dataset is longer, so I would like to have a code that automatically identifies a new day.

edit: full dataset below

```r
structure(list(Zeit = c("11:35:00 AM", "12:43:00 PM", "12:48:00 PM", 
"12:53:00 PM", "12:58:00 PM", "1:03:00 PM", "1:08:00 PM", "1:13:00 PM", 
"1:18:00 PM", "1:23:00 PM", "1:28:00 PM", "1:33:00 PM", "1:38:00 PM", 
"1:43:00 PM", "1:48:00 PM", "1:53:00 PM", "1:58:00 PM", "2:03:00 PM", 
"2:30:00 PM", "2:45:00 PM", "3:00:00 PM", "3:15:00 PM", "3:30:00 PM", 
"3:45:00 PM", "4:00:00 PM", "4:15:00 PM", "4:30:00 PM", "4:45:00 PM", 
"5:00:00 PM", "5:15:00 PM", "5:30:00 PM", "5:45:00 PM", "6:00:00 PM", 
"6:15:00 PM", "6:30:00 PM", "6:45:00 PM", "7:00:00 PM", "7:15:00 PM", 
"7:30:00 PM", "7:45:00 PM", "8:00:00 PM", "8:15:00 PM", "8:30:00 PM", 
"8:45:00 PM", "9:00:00 PM", "9:15:00 PM", "9:30:00 PM", "9:45:00 PM", 
"10:00:00 PM", "10:15:00 PM", "10:45:00 PM", "11:15:00 PM", "11:45:00 PM", 
"12:15:00 AM", "12:45:00 AM", "1:15:00 AM", "1:45:00 AM", "2:15:00 AM", 
"2:45:00 AM", "3:15:00 AM", "3:45:00 AM", "4:15:00 AM"), SRB = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0546352106, 1.89348740676, 14.16501124644, 
33.21026613524, 45.19095110716, 51.16722074468, 46.13852290212, 
38.99889779356, 31.72792609956, 26.59602736844, 23.91280426588, 
18.5369761618, 13.35816793588, 10.76876382292, 8.55463566836, 
7.29746120772, 5.824503071, 4.16390695508, 3.49779212892, 3.36644554348, 
2.5877479298, 2.24999956724, 2.27814526412, 2.10927108284, 1.94977880052, 
1.84657791196, 1.64017613484, 1.48068385252, 1.49006575148, 1.3211915702, 
1.35871916604, 1.58388474108, 1.40562866084, 1.39624676188, 1.16169928788, 
1.0397346014, 0.98344320764, 0.78642332948, 0.7582776326, 0.67384054196, 
0.51434825964, 0.46743876484, 0.39238357316, 0.0827809074800001, 
0.0264895137199999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-62L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we can assume that any back-track in time-of-day means "tomorrow" and no days are skipped, then we can do:

```r
out <- dat |>
  transform(Zeit2 = as.POSIXct(paste("2023-10-24", Zeit), format = "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p")) |>
  transform(Zeit2 = Zeit2 + 86400 * cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(Zeit2) < 0)))
out
#           Zeit      SRB               Zeit2
# 43  8:30:00 PM 1.039735 2023-10-24 20:30:00
# 44  8:45:00 PM 0.983443 2023-10-24 20:45:00
# 45  9:00:00 PM 0.786423 2023-10-24 21:00:00
# 46  9:15:00 PM 0.758278 2023-10-24 21:15:00
# 47  9:30:00 PM 0.673841 2023-10-24 21:30:00
# 48  9:45:00 PM 0.514348 2023-10-24 21:45:00
# 49 10:00:00 PM 0.467439 2023-10-24 22:00:00
# 50 10:15:00 PM 0.392384 2023-10-24 22:15:00
# 51 10:45:00 PM 0.082781 2023-10-24 22:45:00
# 52 11:15:00 PM 0.026490 2023-10-24 23:15:00
# 53 11:45:00 PM 0.000000 2023-10-24 23:45:00
# 54 12:15:00 AM 0.000000 2023-10-25 00:15:00
# 55 12:45:00 AM 0.000000 2023-10-25 00:45:00
# 56  1:15:00 AM 0.000000 2023-10-25 01:15:00
# 57  1:45:00 AM 0.000000 2023-10-25 01:45:00
# 58  2:15:00 AM 0.000000 2023-10-25 02:15:00
# 59  2:45:00 AM 0.000000 2023-10-25 02:45:00
# 60  3:15:00 AM 0.000000 2023-10-25 03:15:00
# 61  3:45:00 AM 0.000000 2023-10-25 03:45:00
# 62  4:15:00 AM 0.000000 2023-10-25 04:15:00
```

If some backtrack is permitted, then we can change `< 0` to be something more negative, such as `< (-3*3600)` to mean it will never backtrack more than 3 hours (diffs are in seconds).

I tend to prefer keeping date and time together in one field, but if you want to keep them separate, then just use `as.Date(trunc(.))`:

```r
out |>
  transform(Datum = as.Date(trunc(Zeit2)))
#           Zeit      SRB               Zeit2      Datum
# 43  8:30:00 PM 1.039735 2023-10-24 20:30:00 2023-10-24
# 44  8:45:00 PM 0.983443 2023-10-24 20:45:00 2023-10-24
# 45  9:00:00 PM 0.786423 2023-10-24 21:00:00 2023-10-24
# 46  9:15:00 PM 0.758278 2023-10-24 21:15:00 2023-10-24
# 47  9:30:00 PM 0.673841 2023-10-24 21:30:00 2023-10-24
# 48  9:45:00 PM 0.514348 2023-10-24 21:45:00 2023-10-24
# 49 10:00:00 PM 0.467439 2023-10-24 22:00:00 2023-10-24
# 50 10:15:00 PM 0.392384 2023-10-24 22:15:00 2023-10-24
# 51 10:45:00 PM 0.082781 2023-10-24 22:45:00 2023-10-24
# 52 11:15:00 PM 0.026490 2023-10-24 23:15:00 2023-10-24
# 53 11:45:00 PM 0.000000 2023-10-24 23:45:00 2023-10-24
# 54 12:15:00 AM 0.000000 2023-10-25 00:15:00 2023-10-25
# 55 12:45:00 AM 0.000000 2023-10-25 00:45:00 2023-10-25
# 56  1:15:00 AM 0.000000 2023-10-25 01:15:00 2023-10-25
# 57  1:45:00 AM 0.000000 2023-10-25 01:45:00 2023-10-25
# 58  2:15:00 AM 0.000000 2023-10-25 02:15:00 2023-10-25
# 59  2:45:00 AM 0.000000 2023-10-25 02:45:00 2023-10-25
# 60  3:15:00 AM 0.000000 2023-10-25 03:15:00 2023-10-25
# 61  3:45:00 AM 0.000000 2023-10-25 03:45:00 2023-10-25
# 62  4:15:00 AM 0.000000 2023-10-25 04:15:00 2023-10-25
```

This works with both the partial and larger dataset in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can start counting a new day after observing the shift from `PM` to `AM`, e.g.,

```
x <- gsub(".*\\s", "", df$Zeit)
cbind(date = as.Date("2023-10-24") + cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(x == "AM") > 0)), df)
```

and you will obtain

```
         date        Zeit         SRB
1  2023-10-24 11:35:00 AM  0.00000000
2  2023-10-24 12:43:00 PM  0.00000000
3  2023-10-24 12:48:00 PM  0.00000000
4  2023-10-24 12:53:00 PM  0.00000000
5  2023-10-24 12:58:00 PM  0.00000000
6  2023-10-24  1:03:00 PM  0.00000000
7  2023-10-24  1:08:00 PM  0.00000000
8  2023-10-24  1:13:00 PM  0.05463521
9  2023-10-24  1:18:00 PM  1.89348741
10 2023-10-24  1:23:00 PM 14.16501125
11 2023-10-24  1:28:00 PM 33.21026614
12 2023-10-24  1:33:00 PM 45.19095111
13 2023-10-24  1:38:00 PM 51.16722074
14 2023-10-24  1:43:00 PM 46.13852290
15 2023-10-24  1:48:00 PM 38.99889779
16 2023-10-24  1:53:00 PM 31.72792610
17 2023-10-24  1:58:00 PM 26.59602737
18 2023-10-24  2:03:00 PM 23.91280427
19 2023-10-24  2:30:00 PM 18.53697616
20 2023-10-24  2:45:00 PM 13.35816794
21 2023-10-24  3:00:00 PM 10.76876382
22 2023-10-24  3:15:00 PM  8.55463567
23 2023-10-24  3:30:00 PM  7.29746121
24 2023-10-24  3:45:00 PM  5.82450307
25 2023-10-24  4:00:00 PM  4.16390696
26 2023-10-24  4:15:00 PM  3.49779213
27 2023-10-24  4:30:00 PM  3.36644554
28 2023-10-24  4:45:00 PM  2.58774793
29 2023-10-24  5:00:00 PM  2.24999957
30 2023-10-24  5:15:00 PM  2.27814526
31 2023-10-24  5:30:00 PM  2.10927108
32 2023-10-24  5:45:00 PM  1.94977880
33 2023-10-24  6:00:00 PM  1.84657791
34 2023-10-24  6:15:00 PM  1.64017613
35 2023-10-24  6:30:00 PM  1.48068385
36 2023-10-24  6:45:00 PM  1.49006575
37 2023-10-24  7:00:00 PM  1.32119157
38 2023-10-24  7:15:00 PM  1.35871917
39 2023-10-24  7:30:00 PM  1.58388474
40 2023-10-24  7:45:00 PM  1.40562866
41 2023-10-24  8:00:00 PM  1.39624676
42 2023-10-24  8:15:00 PM  1.16169929
43 2023-10-24  8:30:00 PM  1.03973460
44 2023-10-24  8:45:00 PM  0.98344321
45 2023-10-24  9:00:00 PM  0.78642333
46 2023-10-24  9:15:00 PM  0.75827763
47 2023-10-24  9:30:00 PM  0.67384054
48 2023-10-24  9:45:00 PM  0.51434826
49 2023-10-24 10:00:00 PM  0.46743876
50 2023-10-24 10:15:00 PM  0.39238357
51 2023-10-24 10:45:00 PM  0.08278091
52 2023-10-24 11:15:00 PM  0.02648951
53 2023-10-24 11:45:00 PM  0.00000000
54 2023-10-25 12:15:00 AM  0.00000000
55 2023-10-25 12:45:00 AM  0.00000000
56 2023-10-25  1:15:00 AM  0.00000000
57 2023-10-25  1:45:00 AM  0.00000000
58 2023-10-25  2:15:00 AM  0.00000000
59 2023-10-25  2:45:00 AM  0.00000000
60 2023-10-25  3:15:00 AM  0.00000000
61 2023-10-25  3:45:00 AM  0.00000000
62 2023-10-25  4:15:00 AM  0.00000000
```

Comment: Thank for the reply, it is an interesting approach. Sadly, I get NAs when I apply it for the entire dataset. See edit, I've added the complete dataset :)

Comment: @DanielAG aha, thanks for pin out the bug. please see my updated solution (w.r.t. your bigger data) and check if it works well